# signs of eigenvalues of quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ be a symmetric real matrix, $M_k:=det(a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq k}$ be its minors and $M_k\ne 0$ for all $k$. Then signs of eigenvalues of $A$ are equal (up to some permutation) to signs of $M_1$, $M_2/M_1$, $\dots$, $M_{n}/M_{n-1}$. It is clear by induction, for example: when we replace $n-1$ to $n$ by adding last row and last column, we either add one positive eigenvalue or add one negative (number of, say, positive eigenvalues may not decrease by variational principle). The sign may be obtained by the sign of product of all eigenvalues, which equals to $M_n$.

What I ask is the reference to this easy, but somehow useful statement. I completely agree that it is not quite of research level and so appreciate its possible closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very closely related to Sylvester's law of inertia (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is called  *Jacobi's formula*.    More details in vol. I, Chap.X,  Section 3 of

> F.R. Gantmacher: The Theory of Matrices, AMS Chelsea Publications

(This is translated from Russian)